# TikZ: update key value in family when calling style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I would like to run some code to decorate a node, and I would like to control that via a TikZ style. I would also like that tikz style to take some parameters, for example in the form `mystyle={arg1=val1, arg2=val2}`, and pass them to the drawing code.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
          % Give a initial value "init" to mystyle/arg
          mystyle/arg/.initial=init,
          % Define a key that actually does the drawing
          mystyle/draw stuff/.code={
            % Just some arrows pointing to the node that use the argument value
            \foreach \angle in {0, 60, ..., 300} {
              \draw[<-] (\tikzlastnode) -- ++(\angle:1cm)
                node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mystyle/arg}};
            }
          },
          % Now define the style
          mystyle/.style={
            % Append code that triggers the key that draws
            append after command=[mystyle/draw stuff],
            % "enter mystyle"
            mystyle/.cd,
            % Import whatever the user specified
            #1
          }
        }
        \node [mystyle={arg=bar}] {foo};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In my understanding, when `mystyle={arg=bar}` is called, `#1` is `{arg=bar}` and it gets imported within `mystyle`, so it should set `/mystyle/arg` to `bar`. So it should generate something like this:

[image: objective]

What I get instead is:

[image: unexpected result]

So `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mystyle/arg}` is never updated to `bar`.

This sounds like should be trivial to do, given that this syntax is used all around TikZ, and yet I cannot figure out how to make this work. Does `#1` have to be expanded in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you try almost works. However, I strongly recommend to put the additional paths in a `pic`, which is made for this. Also you can process the options by saying

```
\tikzset{/tikz/mystyle/.cd,#1}
```

And since you are creating additional nodes I would recommend to save the original one in a macro via

```
\let\myln\tikzlastnode
```

This is the result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
      % Give a initial value "init" to mystyle/arg
      mystyle/arg/.initial=init,
      % Define a key that actually does the drawing
      pics/mystyle/draw stuff/.style={code={
        % Just some arrows pointing to the node that use the argument value
        \let\myln\tikzlastnode
        \tikzset{/tikz/mystyle/.cd,#1}
        \foreach \angle in {0, 60, ..., 300} {
          \draw[<-] (\myln) -- ++(\angle:1cm)
            node[anchor=\angle+180] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mystyle/arg}};
        }
      }},
      % Now define the style
      mystyle/.style={
        % Append code that triggers the key that draws
        append after command={pic{mystyle/draw stuff={#1}}},
        % "enter mystyle"
        mystyle/.cd,
        % Import whatever the user specified
        #1
      }
    }
    \path node [mystyle={arg=bar}] {foo} (4,0) node[mystyle={arg=purr}]{cat};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that in this case you can avoid the `pic` and use `edge`s instead.

Comment: Another great and effective solution from you. You're really impressive.

Comment: That's great! I did not know about `pics`, for future reference: *PGF Manual, chapter III, section 18 "Pics: Small Pictures on Paths"*.  
Also: is it then necessary at all to pass `#1` into `mystyle./style`? Wouldn't it suffice to forward that into `/mystyle/draw stuff`?

Comment: @PietroSaccardi It depends on what you want to do. If you want to be able to pass several keys to the pic, I think that this method is one of the simplest. If you are sure that there will always be just a single key, then you do not need it.